# Using ASP.NET default Model Binders with DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to use the default ASP.NET MVC model binders but I'm having issues with binding DateTime. I've looked at Scott's post [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) but it seems to be too sophisticated. Is there a simpler solution to binding DateTime?

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what your "issues" are. Same as Scott? Different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like Hanselman's solution you could try Castle's binders. They work like [this](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/documentation/trunk/usersguide/smartcontroller.html#date) and they can be [used through MvcContrib](http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=258).